# iOS 11 AVPlayerViewController Disable Pinch / Drag Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerViewController setup to play a video and them I am in-bedding the VC's view in a custom view controller.

But if they user tries they can move the video around by 2 finger grabbing. How do I disable this? Thanks!

See Below:

[image: Example of issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this before start playing video

```
var positions = [Int]()
for (idx, recognizer) in (playerVC.view.subviews[0].gestureRecognizers?.enumerated())! {
    if recognizer is UIPinchGestureRecognizer || recognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        positions.append(idx)
    }
}
for position in positions {
    playerVC.view.subviews[0].gestureRecognizers?.remove(at: position)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More safe way of doing it:

```
    let recognizers: [UIGestureRecognizer] = view.subviews.first?.gestureRecognizers ?? []
    for (idx, recognizer) in recognizers.enumerated() {
        if recognizer is UIPinchGestureRecognizer || recognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            positions.append(idx)
        }
    }
    for position in positions.reversed() {
        view.subviews.first?.gestureRecognizers?.remove(at: position)
    }
```

if you don't use `positions.reversed()` app may crash when removes the first item and the array gets resized.